# Asterisk variable maximum length

Tags: asterisk, voip

I am new to asterisk , I have  searched for  limitation for the max length of  asterisk's UAC parameters

ex: username,secret,callerid,fromuser

I have googled for the same but didnt find the information on the same, but in asterisk source directory  channels/sip/include/sip.h  , i have seen below lines

char username[256]
 char secret[256]

what is the max length allowed for UAC parameters in asterisk?

Comment: It's difficult to see how this is a programming question. You should ask on [sf]

Answer (score 2):

Most of asterisk use 255 maxed strings for line parsing.

As result it is not recommended do lines more then 255 in any config files.

That is per-line limits(not only variable length)

So for example if you are using

```
username = something
```

then "something" must be less then 255 - 12=243.

There are also SAME limit in parsing sip headers in most of devices. As result thoose variable have be MUCH less size.

For example INVITE packets usually have

```
From: "callerid" <sip:username@46.4.111.111:5061>;tag=as3ad441f7
```

So that mean with username more then 200 you can have issues.